# Java Dice Game - Question regarding a "goal" number

Tags: java

I'm writing a code for a dice game where certain numbers allow you to win, certain numbers allow you to lose and another set of numbers will then become the goal number that you need to achieve. So for example, if you roll a 9 you win, if you roll a 12 you lose. But if you roll a 10, that number becomes the goal and if you roll it again, you win. But if you roll a 13 you lose. I'm struggling to comprehend how I could make that last portion work, how to hold a goal number and either make the user win or lose.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceTestZ{

    static int roll()
    {
        int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;

        return die1;
    }


    static boolean playerWins(int dieSum)// I then created a method that would return a boolean if the sum of two of my random numbers were equal to the winning numbers.
{
       return dieSum == 9 || dieSum == 11 || dieSum == 18 || dieSum == 24;
}


    static boolean playerLoses(int dieSum)// This method is the exact same as the one above it, but this method is true when the sum of the dice equals the losing numbers.
{
        return dieSum == 6 || dieSum == 12 || dieSum == 13 || dieSum == 17 || dieSum == 19 || dieSum == 23; 
}

    static boolean playerSets(int dieSum)// This method is the exact same as the ones above it, but this method is true when the sum of the dice equals any of the goal numbers.
{
        return dieSum == 22 || dieSum == 21 || dieSum == 20 || dieSum == 16 || dieSum == 15 || dieSum == 14 || dieSum == 10 || dieSum == 8 || dieSum == 7 || dieSum == 5 || dieSum == 4; 
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the CocoPanther Dice Game!");
    System.out.println("Created by Noah Ilovar.");
    System.out.println("In this game we will roll 4 dice. If you roll a 9,11,18 or 24 you win. But if you roll a 6, 12, 13, 17, 19 or 23 you lose.");
    System.out.println("If you roll any other number that number becomes the new goal and if it is rolled you win. But if you roll an 13, you lose");

    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String inNext =in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome,"+inNext);


    while(true)
    {
        String again = "y";
        int die1 = roll();
        int die2 = roll();
        int die3 = roll();
        int die4 = roll();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int dieSum = die1 + die2 + die3 + die4;

        System.out.println("You've rolled a " +dieSum);

        if(playerWins(dieSum))
        {
            System.out.print("Congratulations, you've won!");

        }

        if(playerLoses(dieSum))
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you've lost the game.");

        }

        if(playerSets(dieSum))
        {
            System.out.println("You've rolled a goal number! Roll it again to win.");

        }

            System.out.println(" Roll them again (y=yes)? ");
            again = keyboard.nextLine();

        }
    }
}
```